# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Why was [my answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/77747/819) deleted? I don't really mind, and I certainly don't think it was a good answer: it was based on nothing but anecdotal evidence, my own experience, with no legal reference to back it up.  I wasn't sure that was good enough here, so I even raised a mod attention flag asking the mod team to look into it and delete if they felt that was appropriate.

The thing is that the mod who handled my flag said the answer was fine, but then a few days later I see it was deleted by a mod with no explanation given. So can someone please explain why that answer was deleted? I stress that I really don't mind and I'm sure the mod was right to delete, I would just like to understand the reasons behind it for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Because it's an anecdote, not an answer**

We are a Q&A site, not a forum. Answers must **be** answers, not stories.

In the context of this site, the question is, in summary, "What can I legally do if I find my stolen bike?" Your post told a story about a similar event that happened to you many years ago. It didn't address whether what happened was legal (many illegal things happen every day) or if it was legal then, is it legal now.

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: Yep, that's fair. But you might want to discuss this with the other mods in your team since I was explicitly told otherwise. It's also a bit strange that the answer was deleted with no comment or explanation. It would be nice to leave an explanatory comment next time so your users can understand.

Comment: @terdon Law.SE has some somewhat heightened citation requirements.

Comment: @Trish which is why I had flagged my answer for mod attention, precisely because I wasn't sure it was good enough. However, a mod replied to my flag telling me it was fine and then the answer was deleted without comment. I have absolutely no problem with the answer being deleted, it wasn't a good answer, just a personal anecdote. However, getting conflicting information and no explanation when an answer is deleted is a problem. Mods should explain why when they delete non-offensive/spam content. The OP is notified of mod comments on a deleted answer, so all it takes is leaving a comment.